# Show database data on listview

Tags: android, sql, listview

I starting with android's SQL database, content providers, etc... I got I'm my app implemented a SQL database. I access this database with a Content Provider, and in my ListActivity, I use a ResourceCursorAdapter to access this data.

I have implemented all the methods and it works fine, but when showing the data of the database on the listview, I'm using the previous method I had implemented to use with an ArrayAdapter.

I have to say that it works fine this way, but due to I'm learning about this concepts, I would like to do it right, without using the ArrrayList, but I don't know how to do this.

This is the relevant code:

```
public class TravelListActivity extends ListActivity {

    private TravelsCursorAdapter mAdapter;

    final class TravelsCursorAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {
    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public TravelsCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 0);
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, parent, false);

        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
        TextView textView1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
        holder.text1 = textView1;
        holder.text2 = textView2;
        view.setTag(holder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        String city = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY));
        String country = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY));
        int year = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR));
        String note = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE));

        holder.text1.setText(city + " (" + country + ")");
        holder.text2.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.year) + " " + year);
    }
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView text1;
    TextView text2;
}
```

onCreate method

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
    mAdapter = new TravelsCursorAdapter(this, c);
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Finally, this is the way I'm doing now, and what I want to modify according to the resources I'm using:

```
public ArrayList<TravelInfo> getTravelsList(){

    ArrayList<TravelInfo> travels = new ArrayList<TravelInfo>();
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, Travels.YEAR);

    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()){
        int cityIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.CITY);
        int countryIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.COUNTRY);
        int yearIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.YEAR);
        int noteIndex = c.getColumnIndex(Travels.NOTE);

        do {
            String city = c.getString(cityIndex);
            String country = c.getString(countryIndex);
            int year = c.getInt(yearIndex);
            String note = c.getString(noteIndex);

            TravelInfo travel = new TravelInfo(city, country, year, note);
            travels.add(travel);
        }
        while (c.moveToNext());
        c.close();
    }
    return travels;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand where you are using this getTravelsList() method now

Comment: @Tomasz Chabinka You're right, I have had a look and I'm not using it now, but it still loads the data on the listview, so... this means that I don't need this method any more?

Comment: Yep, all work related to database is make in bindView method. Only difference now is that your query returns not-ordered data. Earlier query returns data ordered by Travels.YEAR column.

You can change this by changing `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);` into `Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(TravelsProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, Travels.YEAR);` in onCreate method